# How to find partial number match in whole column?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to find if a number in A2, lets say 123, can be found in any row of Column B. This number might be repeated e.g. 123,123 or it might be combined with text or another number e.g. 123,456 or RF939,123

I have found this formula that works to find if the number is present for a single row:

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"",1))>0
```

And I have found this formula that works to find a match for a partial string in a column:

```
=MATCH("*"&A2&"*",$B:$B,0)>0
```

I have *yet* to find one that will work for numbers or text/number strings.

Possibly the **SUBSTITUTE** method could be expanded to work with an array, but I am not too savvy with array forumlas.

Is this possible or will I have to use VBA?

Comment: What do you want to return?  The row it matches?

Comment: just a true or false would be nice, the row number would be a bonus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&A2&",",","&$B$1:$B$100&","))),1)
```

Or if you do not care about the `,` deliniating the matches so `123` will be found in `51234` then

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,$B$1:$B$100))),1)
```